# unlock developer options for new user?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, multi-user, developer-options

is it possible to enable/unlock developer options for a second user
**Android-version: 7.1 nougat**

does it reqire root access to enable it

Comment: i am not aware of how android handles multi-user but i can imagine only user 0 is allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@alecxs is right.

Enable developer settings you want as the main user; then it will be the same across all users (at least, this is what worked for me). Note that often if you are connecting to something there will be a prompt on your device asking if it's okay to connect to the computer/application. You need to switch back to the main user to accept the prompt, then it should work on all users

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800577/can-i-enable-developer-mode-for-a-user-other-than-the-owner-on-an-android-tablet)

[Another similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223748/android-4-2-developer-settings-still-unavailable)